# Why does the println (Object x) method in PrintStream.java call String.valueOf() from outside the synchronized block?

Tags: java

Why does the println (Object x) method in PrintStream.java call String.valueOf() from outside the synchronized block?

Why not use an existing print (Object obj)?

for performance?

Comment: `String s = String.valueOf(x);` is a `read only`operation, which do not require to be in synchronized blocks. To avoid wait times due to locks, everything that is not required to be synchronized, should be outside of the sync-block. So yes, it's for performance.

Comment: There is no reason why it should call it inside the `synchronized` block. The block is only there to protect the writer's own buffers and the underlying stream. It doesn't have anything to do with the object being printed. These blocks should be as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf(x)` calls the `toString()` method on `x`. The implementation of this method can do anything, including synchronization on this or other `PrintStream` instances. To avoid deadlocks, the `String.valueOf()` needs to be called outside of a lock.

The `print` method cannot be reused because the line break needs to be printed immediately after the object, even if there are other threads writing other data to the same `PrintStream`. To achieve this, `print` and `newLine` are called from within a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I need help with further understanding.
In the same case as calling a static method such as String.valueOf() in a synchonized block.
Can you tell me in which case a deadlock is occurring?

Comment: Imagine you have two PrintStream instances and two objects with custom toString() implementations. The first object synchronizes on the second PrintStream instance, and the second one synchronizes on the first one. Then you have two threads, one of which prints the first object to the first PrintStream, and the second prints the second object to the second PrintStream.